# Python: Adding hours and minutes

Tags: python, datetime, addition

I'm quite new at python and I'm trying to add some data that's formatted as H:MM:SS. I tried using strptime but I'm still failing. Can anybody help me?

```
            struct_t_time = time.strptime(t_time, '%k:%M:%S')
    if 'V' in t_type and 'Inc' in t_dir and 'Acc' in t_resp:
        inc= inc + 1
        t_in_time = str(struct_t_time) + str(struct_t_time)
    else:
        if t_type == "V" and t_dir == "Out" and t_resp == "CCN":
            out = out + 1
            t_out_time = str(struct_t_time) + str(struct_t_time)
    total_calls = inc + out
    total_time = t_in_time + t_out_time
```

I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvmkr.py", line 31, in <module>
struct_t_time = time.strptime(t_time, '%k:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 467, in _strptime_time
return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
(bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'k' is a bad directive in format '%k:%M:%S'
```

Comment: why you are using k instead of H?

Comment: Is your hour really only a single digit?

Comment: As a side note, the `datetime` module has support for operations on dates and times...

Comment: @Azad Desperation, really. The data that I'm trying to parse usually has this format "0:05:41", and I thought maybe H doesn't get the single digit hours so I tried using different things. I also tried using H and got a formatting error.

Comment: @Andy yes it is. Maybe I could somehow add another 0 in front.

Comment: look at the table in here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior there is no %k in there

Comment: @Azad OHH. I was looking at a different datetime document. *facepalm*